# Manipulating with NSMutableArray And NSMutableDictionary Objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have An NSMutableArray of NSMutableDictionary 
Which Looks like this

Object 1 of Array 
    value=1   forKey=a
    value=2   forKey=b
    value=3   forKey=e

Object 2 of Array
    value=4   forKey=a
    value=5   forKey=b
    value=6   forKey=c
.
.
.Continues

Now What  I need is  to Change the Value For key "a" where value is 5, change it ,12 . For Example, the Changed Object 2  Will be

Object 2 of Array 
    value=4         forKey=a
    value=12    forKey=b
    value=6         forKey=c

I need it to do it without **Looping** can any understand my Question and give me the answer.

Comment: Why do you need to do it without looping? Any solution I could suggest would almost certainly use either explicit or internal looping.

Comment: Can you share your most effective suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (assuming your dictionaries are type NSMutableDictionary):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [yourArray objectAtIndex: 1];
[dict setObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 12] forKey: @"b"];
```